# URL rewrite remove slash at end

Tags: url-rewriting

I have this working code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)\/$ /news/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and I want to remove the / at the end of the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator); this would give something like this (see change on the two last lines):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ /page.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)\$ /news/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But if I leave it this way when I try to reach the file, for example, `www.domain.com/register` instead of `www.domain.com/register/`, it throws me error 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this easy statement:

```
(\/{0,1})
```

It says "*There can be either one `/` or zero `/` - both is fine*". When applied the last two rows, whole result should look like this I presume:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\$ /page.php?page=$1(\/{0,1}) [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)\$ /news/article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In case it still won't work correctly, try to add `(\/{0,1})` to the end of the last row as well.